# How to get extra data from MFC Tab Control (TabCtrl)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, ctabctrl

I have created an MFC dialog based application to study tab control. In a tab control it is possible to set application specific data to each tab.
I am trying to understand how to set/retrieve the data for individual tabs of the tab control.

Here is a sample application I am creating. Each tab of the control is supposed to store some GPU info.

[image: Tab Control]

As I understand, there are 3 steps to add application specific data.

1. Create a user defined structure, whose 1st member should be of type `TCITEMHEADER`.

   ```
   struct GPU {
       std::wstring name;
       int busid;
   };
   struct tabData {
       TCITEMHEADER tabItemHeader;
       GPU gpu;
   };
   ```
2. Tell the tab control about the extra bytes, the user defined structure is going to take. This I am doing in `DoDataExchange()`.

   ```
   int extraBytes = sizeof(tabData) - sizeof(TCITEMHEADER);
   auto status = tabCtrl1.SetItemExtra(extraBytes);
   ```
3. Set user defined data while adding tabs.

   ```
   static int tabCtr = 0;
   tabData td;
   td.tabItemHeader.pszText = _T("TabX");
   td.tabItemHeader.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
   td.gpu.name = L"AMD NVIDIA";
   td.gpu.busid = 101;
   TabCtrl_InsertItem(tabCtrl1.GetSafeHwnd(), tabCtr, &td);
   ```

Now to get the data, we simply have to call `TabCtrl_GetItem()`.

```
tabData td2;
td2.tabItemHeader.pszText = new TCHAR[20];
td2.tabItemHeader.cchTextMax = 20;

td2.tabItemHeader.mask = TCIF_TEXT;

td2.gpu.busid = 0;

TabCtrl_GetItem(tabCtrl1.GetSafeHwnd(), 0, &td2);
```

But as we can see in the following image. I do get the tab text (pszText member - data Item 1 in image), but not the extra data that I had associated with it previously (Data Items 2 and 3 in image).

[image: Tab Control get Item]

Which step am I missing? 
Why is the structure associated with application defined data not getting populated?

**Additional Info**

Here is the complete code for the application.

**CPP File:**

> ```
> // tabCtrlStackOverflowDlg.cpp : implementation file
> //
>
> #include "stdafx.h"
> #include "tabCtrlStackOverflow.h"
> #include "tabCtrlStackOverflowDlg.h"
> #include "afxdialogex.h"
> #include <string>
>
> #ifdef _DEBUG
> #define new DEBUG_NEW
> #endif
>
>
> struct GPU {
>     std::wstring name;
>     int busid;
> };
>
> struct tabData
> {
>     TCITEMHEADER tabItemHeader;
>     GPU gpu;
> };
>
>
>
> CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg::CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
>   : CDialogEx(IDD_TABCTRLSTACKOVERFLOW_DIALOG, pParent)
> {
>   m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
> }
>
> void CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
> {
>     CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
>     DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_TAB1, tabCtrl1);
>
>     int extraBytes = sizeof(tabData) - sizeof(TCITEMHEADER);
>
>     auto status = tabCtrl1.SetItemExtra(extraBytes);
>
>     wchar_t *t = status ? L"SetItemExtra() success" : L"SetItemExtra() fail";
>
>     GetDlgItem(IDC_STATUSTEXT)->SetWindowTextW(t);
> }
>
> BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg, CDialogEx)
>   ON_WM_PAINT()
>   ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
>     ON_BN_CLICKED(IDADDTAB, &CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg::OnBnClickedAddtab)
>     ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_GETITEM0, &CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg::OnBnClickedGetitem0)
>     ON_BN_CLICKED(IDCLOSE, &CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg::OnBnClickedClose)
> END_MESSAGE_MAP()
>
>
> // CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg message handlers
>
> BOOL CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg::OnInitDialog()
> {
>   CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();
>
>   // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
>   //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
>   SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
>   SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon
>
>   // TODO: Add extra initialization here
>
>   return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
> }
>
> // If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
> //  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
> //  this is automatically done for you by the framework.
>
> void CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg::OnPaint()
> {
>   if (IsIconic())
>   {
>       CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
>
>       SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);
>
>       // Center icon in client rectangle
>       int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
>       int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
>       CRect rect;
>       GetClientRect(&rect);
>       int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
>       int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;
>
>       // Draw the icon
>       dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
>   }
>   else
>   {
>       CDialogEx::OnPaint();
>   }
> }
>
> // The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
> //  the minimized window.
> HCURSOR CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
> {
>   return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
> }
>
>
>
> void CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg::OnBnClickedAddtab()
> {
>     static int tabCtr = 0;
>     tabData td;
>     td.tabItemHeader.pszText = _T("TabX");
>     td.tabItemHeader.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
>
>     td.gpu.name = L"AMD NVIDIA";
>     td.gpu.busid = 101;
>
>     int status = TabCtrl_InsertItem(tabCtrl1.GetSafeHwnd(), tabCtr, &td);
>
>     wchar_t *t = L"";
>
>     if (status == -1)
>     {
>         t = L"TabCtrl_InsertItem() Fail";
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         t = L"TabCtrl_InsertItem() success";
>     }
>
>     GetDlgItem(IDC_STATUSTEXT)->SetWindowTextW(t);
>     tabCtr++;
> }
>
>
> void CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg::OnBnClickedGetitem0()
> {
>     tabData td2;
>     td2.tabItemHeader.pszText = new TCHAR[20];
>     td2.tabItemHeader.cchTextMax = 20;
>
>     td2.tabItemHeader.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
>
>     td2.gpu.busid = 0;
>
>     if (TabCtrl_GetItem(tabCtrl1.GetSafeHwnd(), 0, &td2) == TRUE)
>     {
>         std::wstring text = td2.tabItemHeader.pszText;
>         text += std::wstring(L" ") + td2.gpu.name;
>         GetDlgItem(IDC_STATUSTEXT)->SetWindowTextW(text.c_str());
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         GetDlgItem(IDC_STATUSTEXT)->SetWindowTextW(_T("TabCtrl_GetItem()
> error"));
>     }
> }
>
>
> void CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg::OnBnClickedClose()
> {
>     CDialog::OnCancel();
> }
> ```

**Header File:**

> ```
> // tabCtrlStackOverflowDlg.h : header file
> //
>
> #pragma once
> #include "afxcmn.h"
>
>
> // CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg dialog
> class CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg : public CDialogEx
> {
> // Construction
> public:
>   CtabCtrlStackOverflowDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL); // standard constructor
>
> // Dialog Data
> #ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
>   enum { IDD = IDD_TABCTRLSTACKOVERFLOW_DIALOG };
> #endif
>
>   protected:
>   virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
>
>
> // Implementation
> protected:
>   HICON m_hIcon;
>
>   // Generated message map functions
>   virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();
>   afx_msg void OnPaint();
>   afx_msg HCURSOR OnQueryDragIcon();
>   DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
> public:
>     CTabCtrl tabCtrl1;
>     afx_msg void OnBnClickedAddtab();
>     afx_msg void OnBnClickedGetitem0();
>     afx_msg void OnBnClickedClose();
> };
> ```

**Solution Summary**

From [Barmak Shemirani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48059969/981766) here are the 3 reasons my code wasn't working. Must read his answer for better understanding.

1. `TCIF_PARAM` must be set in mask, while doing `TCM_INSERTITEM`, and `TCM_GETITEM`.
2. I was using local variables created on stack (tabData td2; object). The reference to this variable was becoming invalid as soon as it was going out of scope.
3. Using std::wstring in the structure being used for `TCM_INSERTITEM`. It is better to use data types whose size can be accurately be determined (like plain old data types.).

As Barmak Shemirani points out in comments, the documentation for `TCITEMHEADER` is scarce. His answer provides a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Conflict with documentation***

*Documentation for [TCITEMHEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760556(v=vs.85).aspx) does not mention using `TCIF_PARAM` flag. Maybe that's a mistake in documention!*

---

It's better if `SetItemExtra` is moved to `OnInitDialog` after default procedure is called. This ensures `SetItemExtra` is called only once when control is empty.

The structure `GPU` has a `std::wstring` member whose data size is unknown at the start. `TCM_INSERTITEM` cannot make a copy of this data unless you have a simple POD structure.

To store the data in the tab, replace `std::wstring` with `wchar_t name[100]` so that data is a simple POD structure with fixed size.

```
struct GPU
{
    //std::wstring name;
    wchar_t name[100];
    int busid;
};

struct tabData
{
    TCITEMHEADER tabItemHeader;
    GPU gpu;
};

void CMyDialog::OnBnClickedAddtab()
{
    int index = tab.GetItemCount();
    wchar_t tabname[50];
    wsprintf(tabname, L"Tab %d", index);
    tabData sdata = { 0 };
    sdata.tabItemHeader.mask = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_PARAM;
    sdata.tabItemHeader.pszText = tabname;
    wsprintf(sdata.gpu.name, L"AMD NVIDIA %d", index);
    sdata.gpu.busid = 101;
    tab.SendMessage(TCM_INSERTITEM, index, (LPARAM)(TCITEMHEADER*)(&sdata));
}

void CMyDialog::OnBnClickedGetitem0()
{
    int index = tab.GetCurSel();
    tabData data = { 0 };
    wchar_t buf[20] = { 0 };
    data.tabItemHeader.pszText = buf;
    data.tabItemHeader.cchTextMax = sizeof(buf)/sizeof(wchar_t);
    data.tabItemHeader.mask = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_PARAM;
    if(tab.SendMessage(TCM_GETITEM, index, (LPARAM)(TCITEMHEADER*)(&data)))
    {
        CString str;
        str.Format(L"%d %s", data.gpu.busid, data.gpu.name);
        GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC1)->SetWindowText(str);
    }
}
```

---

**Alternative method:**

If `std::wstring name;` cannot be replaced with `wchar_t` buffer, we have to define a separate permanent data, for example using `std::vector`. Then we use the `lParam` value in `TCITEM` to point to the vector.

This method only needs the standard 4 bytes of `lParam`, it doesn't require `TCITEMHEADER` and `SetItemExtra`. You can even define `std::vector<GPU>`. Example:

```
std::vector<tabData> m_data;

BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    tabData data;

    data.gpu.name = L"AMD NVIDIA1";
    data.gpu.busid = 101;
    m_data.push_back(data);

    data.gpu.name = L"AMD NVIDIA2";
    data.gpu.busid = 102;
    m_data.push_back(data);

    return TRUE;
}

void CMyDialog::OnBnClickedAddtab()
{
    static int tabCtr = 0;
    if(tabCtr >= (int)m_data.size())
        return;

    TCITEM item = { 0 };
    item.pszText = _T("TabX");
    item.mask = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_PARAM;
    item.lParam = (LPARAM)&m_data[tabCtr];
    tab.InsertItem(tabCtr, &item);

    tabCtr++;
}

void CMyDialog::OnBnClickedGetitem0()
{
    TCITEM item = { 0 };
    item.mask = TCIF_TEXT | TCIF_PARAM;
    if(tab.GetItem(tab.GetCurSel(), &item) == TRUE)
    {
        tabData* ptr = (tabData*)item.lParam;
        CString str;
        str.Format(L"%d %s", ptr->gpu.busid, ptr->gpu.name.c_str());
        GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC1)->SetWindowText(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: You pointed out that td is temporary variable, and that gpu has a member whose size is not known. These two hints helped me figure out the correct solution. In addition to these two, I had to use TCIF_PARAM flag while inserting/getting data. I do not want to use TCITEM struct, instead a user defined struct like tabData. If you could incorporate in your answer, how to use tabData instead of TCITEM, and tell about the usage of TCIF_PARAM flag in such case, I will mark your answer accepted. Otherwise your answer is helpful, only slight addition has to be made.

Comment: What are the restrictions in your program? I added a second method which uses `TCITEMHEADER` to store in the tab. But you can't use `std::wstring` with this second method. If you are able to use permanent data in your application (example `m_data`), then it's safer and easier to avoid using `TCITEMHEADER`. Documentation for `TCITEMHEADER` is scarce, a web search on `TCITEMHEADER` landed me back on this question.

Comment: I want to use user defined structure, along with `TCITEMHEADER`.  Thanks to you my code now works. You were right in pointing out that `TCIF_PARAM` is not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Is setting extra item size in `OnInitDialog` correct? `OnInitDialog` gets called before `DoDataExchange`, hence the variable `tab` in the following code might not have been associated with the tab control by then. `tab.SetItemExtra(sizeof(tabData) - sizeof(TCITEMHEADER));`

Comment: `CDialogEx::OnInitDialog` will call `DoDataExchange`, so the tab control will be ready after `CDialogEx::OnInitDialog` (not before). I tried it in `DoDataExchange` that works too. `DoDataExchange` is called a second time when dialog is destroyed, I guess the program ingores the call to `SetItemExtra` and it doesn't cause any harm.